# How to find the 1st day of a previosu month in SQL Server Reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am trying to set a default date to be the fist day of the previous April.
I have found expressions for the 1st day of previous month

```
=DateValue(DateAdd("M",-1,DateAdd("D",-(Day(Now)-1),Now)))
```

And I have found an expression for 1st day of April for current year (`=CDATE("04/01/"+CStr(Year(NOW())`) but I always need to find the previous April, not April of the current year.

Is anybody able to help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIF(Today.Month>=4,DateSerial(today.Year,4,1),DateSerial(today.Year-1,4,1))
```

Note if you run the report in April or after you will get the current year april, if you run the report in march or before you will get the last year april.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, It didn't but I think it was my fault as after re-reading my question it is misleading. It showed 01/04/2015. If I run the report now (August 2016) the expression should return 01/04/16, but if I had run it in March 2016, then it should show 01/04/15.

Comment: What do you mean with If I had run in March it should show 01/04/15? what should happen if you run the report after and before march?. Explain better

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, I'll try and explain better. . The expression I need should always show the last April. So if I run the report today (August 2016) the expression should return the date 01/04/2016. I just added the expression =DateSerial(today.Year-1,4,1) into the report and run it and it returned 01/04/2015. I want it to show 01/04/2016 (April just gone).

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Thank you very much. Huge help.

Comment: @Freddie, If my answer solved your question you can select it as the correct answer or upvote it. [how to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)